# Open SVG files in XML mode

Tags: images, xml

When opening a vector icon text file for editing, Emacs *first* tries to display it as an image. That is wrong ; If the file has errors, Emacs (25.3.2 - x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) crashes miserably. Well, I *know* it has errors, that why I opened it in a *text editor* in the first place :/

And furthermore, Emacs will hang even if the file doesn't have errors, but just because it cannot render it (like it's just several `path`s with `id`s inside a `svg` grouping tag) which is frustrating to say the least.

How can I make Emacs load text files as text files and not try to render it (because it can't) unless I explicitly told him to?

PS - Yes, I know that I can switch to text-mode by pressing `C-c C-c`.

#### What I tried

```
(add-to-list `auto-mode-alist
             '("\\.svg\\'" . xml-mode))
```

But no, Emacs still crashes on me upon opening my icons.svg file because it tries to render it as an image (and it's actually *several* images) when actually it's not its job.

#### Annex: The SVG code

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <symbol id="cross" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <path d="M17.1 5.2l-2.6-2.6-4.6 4.7-4.7-4.7-2.5 2.6 4.7 4.7-4.7 4.7 2.5 2.5 4.7-4.7 4.6 4.7 2.6-2.5-4.7-4.7"/>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="play" viewBox="0 0 15 15">
    <path d="M690 60H40l330 570L700 60z" />
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: You can open you file with `M-x find-file-literaly` and then `M-x xml-mode`

Comment: Cannot reproduce that problem with emacs 25.3.1 GTK+ on cygwin. What version of emacs do you use?

Comment: FWIW, both on emacs-24 and a reasonably recent emacs-26.0.90 `(add-to-list \`auto-mode-alist '("\\.svg\\'" . xml-mode))` is sufficient to cause the svg file to be opened as xml (tested with `emacs -Q`).

Interestingly, on emacs-24, opening your svg file as an image (i.e. the default) does not cause a crash, while on emacs-26.0.90, it does.

Comment: Also, running `convert your_svg.svg output.png` results in `Aborted (core dumped)`, so it's almost certainly an imagemagick problem.

Comment: @aplaice You are right, not only about add-to-list working in a `emacs -Q` session, but also, in this session my image displays, too!! Well, it's broken, but at least Emacs didn't crash. Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: I've reported the bug of the svg causing emacs to crash, in the form that I observed it, [here](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=29581).

Comment: Had the same problem and the suggested solution didn't seem to work. Try adding `SVG` to `imagemagick-types-inhibit` and then restarting Emacs. Does that help?

Answer (score 4):

You'll probably like to either disable `auto-image-file-mode` or tweak `image-file-name-extensions`.

BTW, if Emacs crashes or hangs for a particular SVG file, I suggest you `M-x report-emacs-bug` about it.  Maybe there's not much Emacs's code can do about it (e.g. the problem is in the SVG rendering livbrary), but it might be a good reason to change the default so that image-mode is not used by default on SVG files (hell, it might even be a security hole).

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. Here is the description of the `auto-image-file-mode` *var*: "auto-image-file-mode’s value is nil

Documentation:
Non-nil if Auto-Image-File mode is enabled.
See the ‘auto-image-file-mode’ command
for a description of this minor mode.
Setting this variable directly does not take effect;
either customize it (see the info node ‘Easy Customization’)
or call the function ‘auto-image-file-mode’." but even customizing it (? I don't get this "Setting this variable directly does not take effect" weirdness) doesn't change anything: Emacs crashes :[

Comment: I might add that eval `(auto-image-file-mode -1)` doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that does 2 things:

1. Attempt to open any XML file in nXML mode, and this obviously needs to include SVG files.
2. If such a file is an SVG file, then define `C-c C-c` to `image-mode`.

For the first item, I use `magic-mode-alist` to select `nxml-mode` on some sequences at the beginning of the buffer: `<?xml`, some DOCTYPE line with XHTML, and `<svg` followed by a newline character, a space, or `>`. This will work with SVG files that use an XML prolog or not (I assume no initial spaces, but this could be changed). Here's the code:

```lisp
(when (boundp 'magic-mode-alist)
  (push '("\\`<\\(\\?xml\\|!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML\\|svg[\n >]\\)"
          . nxml-mode)
        magic-mode-alist)
)
```

For the second item, I use code for a `find-file` hook:

```lisp
(defun my-find-file-hook ()
  (when (and (string= major-mode "nxml-mode")
             (save-excursion
               (and (re-search-forward "<[a-z]" 1024 t)
                    (progn (backward-char)
                           (looking-at "svg[\n >]")))))
    (global-set-key "\C-c\C-c" 'image-mode)))
(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'my-find-file-hook)
```

If the buffer is in nXML mode, it searches for the root element and if it is `svg`, then it defines `C-c C-c`. Note that this is just a heuristic. In particular, a `<svg` sequence in an initial XML comment could yield a false positive, but I think that this never occurs in practice.